# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'google_mobile_ads' not found, flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm having this problem with flutter, I really don't know what to do, I've already tried deleting pods and podfiles, flutter clean and reinstalling everything but nothing, even the google_mobile_ads library is updated, I just can't figure out what to do, below I leave you some Images

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgUfM.png)

[Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6jSq.png)

**click on the blue to view the images**